# Composition of dual maps is well-defined

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A, B: V\to W$ be linear maps.
Then $A^* :W^*\to V^*$ satisfies $A^*(\omega) = \omega\circ A$. Define $B^*$ similarly.

However, I don't see why $(A\circ B)^* = B^*\circ A^*$.

Since $A^*, B^*: V\to \mathbb{R}$, how can we compose them if $A^*$ doesn't have the same codomain as $V$'s domain.

Comment: You said that $A^* \colon W^* \to V^*$, and also $A^* \colon V \to \Bbb R$. How is that possible? By the way, it should be $B \colon U \to V$, so that $A \circ B$ makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in this context we are only considering real vector spaces.

You seem to have several definitions confused. In order for $A \circ B$ to make sense, we must have $A: V\to W$ and $B:U \to V$ for some vector spaces $U,V,W$. Note that for any vector space $V$, the dual space $V^*$ is the space of all linear maps from $V$ to $\Bbb R$. That is, $V^*$ is the space of all *functionals* over $V$.

For a given functional $\omega \in W^*$ (which is to say that $\omega:W \to \Bbb R$ is linear), we define $A^* (\omega)$ to be the map $\omega \circ A$. Note that $A^*(\omega)$ is an element of $V^*$, which is to say that $A^*(\omega):V \to \Bbb R$ and $A^*(\omega)$ is linear. This means that $A^*$ is a function whose input is one function (an element of $W^*$) and whose output is another function (an element of $V^*$). This does **not** mean that $A^*:V \to \Bbb R$. In fact, we have seen that for an input $\omega \in W^*$, the output $A^*(\omega)$ is an element of $V^*$, so that $A^*:W^* \to V^*$.

With all that established: to show that $(A \circ B)^* = B^* \circ A^*$, we need to show that for any functional $\omega \in W^*$, $(A \circ B)^*(\omega)$ is yields the same result (i.e. the same element of $U^*$) as $(B^* \circ A^*)(\omega)$. To show that this is the case, simply apply the definition of the dual map as needed.
$$
(A \circ B)^*(\omega) = \omega \circ (A \circ B),\\
(B^* \circ A^*)(\omega) = B^*(A^*(\omega)) = B^*(\omega \circ A) = (\omega \circ A)\circ B.
$$